# Creating a vertical histogram in Java (without arrays)

Tags: java, histogram

The program creates a horizontal histogram. How would I change it to a vertical histogram with the categories listed at the top and the asterisks' following under each category. Here's the kicker - without using any arrays (only loops and if statements).

```
    System.out.print("0-29: ");
    for(int v = 0; v < countertwo; v++) {
        System.out.print("*"); }

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.print("30-39: ");
    for(int v = 0; v < counterthree; v++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.print("40-69: ");
    for(int v = 0; v < counterfour; v++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.print("70-100: ");
    for(int v = 0; v < counterfive; v++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
```

Comment: Use the maximum value to determine the hight of the histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that to display a vertical histogram (downward) without using arrays, you can do it through using 16 if statements as follows (16 if statements because of the 16 possible outcomes with 4 variables):

```
    System.out.println("0-29  30-39  40-69  70-100");      

    for(int v = 0; v<countertwo||v<counterthree||v<counterfour||v<counterfive;) {

        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println(" *      *      *      *");
            countertwo--; counterthree--; counterfour--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println(" *      *      *");
            countertwo--; counterthree--; counterfour--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println(" *      *             *");
            countertwo--; counterthree--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println(" *      *              ");
            countertwo--; counterthree--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println(" *             *      *");
            countertwo--; counterfour--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println(" *             *       ");
            countertwo--; counterfour--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println(" *                    *");
            countertwo--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo>0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println(" *                     ");
            countertwo--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println("        *      *      *");
            counterthree--; counterfour--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println("        *      *       ");
            counterthree--; counterfour--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println("        *             *");
            counterthree--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree>0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println("        *              ");
            counterthree--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println("               *      *");
            counterfour--; counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour>0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println("               *       ");
            counterfour--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive>0) {
            System.out.println("                      *");
            counterfive--;
        }
        if (countertwo==0 && counterthree==0 && counterfour==0 &&counterfive==0) {
            System.out.println("                       ");   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the height of the histogram by finding the maximum value

```
max = countertwo;
if(counterthree>max)
max = counterthree;
if(counterfour>max)
max = counterfour;
ect
```

alternatively

```
max=Math.max(countetOne, Math.max(countertwo, Math.max(counterthree, Math.max.. ect
```

Display the histogram like this

```
for(int i = max; i > 0; i--) //for each row
{

  System.out.print("     "); // spread out the bars

  if(counterone >= i) //if this bar is this tall
     System.out.print("*");
  else
     System.out.print(" ");

  System.out.print("     "); // spread out the bars

  if(countertwo >= i) //if this bar is this tall
     System.out.print("*");
  else
     System.out.print(" ");

  //Do this for each bar


     System.out.println();
 }

 System.out.println("  X Axis label") //print what labels bars
 //May have to adjust spacing between bars depending on length of this
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I would rather that the histogram displays the axis label at the top and that the graph is displayed downward rather than upward. How would I go about doing that?